# How to get a type from type_info for template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rtti

I have a tree where each node basically looks like this:

```
struct node
{
    std::unordered_set<object*> objects;
    std::map<std::type_index,node> children;
};
```

When i iterate over the tree to add a new type, i want to do a check :

```
std::is_base_of<base,derived>
```

However, the only information i have for the derived type is a `type_index/type_info*`.

Is there anyway i can transform the `type_info*` to a `template` argument?

If not, what are my other options? I guess could call `decltype(*objects.begin())`, but that would require each set in every node to never be empty.

Comment: Templates are compile-time evaluated and you have a `type_info` representing the runtime-type of your objects. How should this ever be possible. You already know their static type, it's `object*` (and that's also what `decltype(*objects.begin())` will return), but that doesn't help you in any way. So templates are entirely out of the question, since the solve a completely different problem and cannot be used for RTTI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want a type `inheritance_checker` such that each instation of it is associated to a type but `inheritance_checker` itself is not. Something similar to `type_ifo` but that can check inheritance relationships at runtime. For example, you want the following to work:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

// Note that a and b have the same type but they are "related" to distinct types.
inheritance_checker a = inheritance_checker::create<A>();
inheritance_checker b = inheritance_checker::create<B>();

assert(   a.is_base_of  (b) );
assert(   a.derives_from(a) ); // derives from or is equal to
assert( ! b.is_base_of  (a) );
assert(   b.derives_from(b) ); // derives from or is equal to
```

If this is the case, I can suggest you something that, unfortunately, can be quite slow! It depends on exceptions.

The basic idea is that if you throw a `B*` then a `catch (A*)` is a match. Hence, we give to `inheritance_checker` the ability to throw and catch pointers to the type given at construction time. But `inheritance_checker` is not a template and therefore this capacity must be provided in a type-erased way. This can be done by storing pointers to functions that have a fixed signature that doesn't depend on the type passed at construction but are capable of throwing/catching pointers to the given type. A possible implementation of `inheritance_checker` is given below.

```
#include <cassert>

class inheritance_checker {

    typedef void (*thrower_t)();
    typedef bool (*catcher_t)(thrower_t);

public:

    template <typename T>
    static inheritance_checker create() {
        return inheritance_checker(concrete_thrower<T>, concrete_catcher<T>);
    } 

    bool is_derived_from(const inheritance_checker& other) const {
        return other.catcher_(thrower_);
    }

    bool is_base_of(const inheritance_checker& other) const {
        return catcher_(other.thrower_);
    }

private:

    template <typename T>
    static void concrete_thrower() {
        throw static_cast<T*>(nullptr);
    }

    template <typename T>
    static bool concrete_catcher(thrower_t thrower) {
        try         { thrower();   }
        catch (T*)  { return true; }
        catch (...) {              }
        return false;
    }

    inheritance_checker(thrower_t thrower, catcher_t catcher) :
        thrower_(thrower), catcher_(catcher) {
    }

    thrower_t thrower_;
    catcher_t catcher_;
};

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public B {};
class D {};

int main() {

    auto a = inheritance_checker::create<A>();
    auto b = inheritance_checker::create<B>();
    auto c = inheritance_checker::create<C>();
    auto d = inheritance_checker::create<D>();

    assert( a.is_base_of(a));
    assert( a.is_base_of(b));
    assert( a.is_base_of(c));
    assert(!a.is_base_of(d));

    assert( a.is_derived_from(a));
    assert(!a.is_derived_from(b));
    assert(!a.is_derived_from(c));
    assert(!a.is_derived_from(d));

    assert(!b.is_base_of(a));
    assert( b.is_base_of(b));
    assert( b.is_base_of(c));
    assert(!b.is_base_of(d));

    assert( b.is_derived_from(a));
    assert( b.is_derived_from(b));
    assert(!b.is_derived_from(c));
    assert(!b.is_derived_from(d));

    assert(!c.is_base_of(a));
    assert(!c.is_base_of(b));
    assert( c.is_base_of(c));
    assert(!c.is_base_of(d));

    assert( c.is_derived_from(a));
    assert( c.is_derived_from(b));
    assert( c.is_derived_from(c));
    assert(!c.is_derived_from(d));

    assert(!d.is_base_of(a));
    assert(!d.is_base_of(b));
    assert(!d.is_base_of(c));
    assert( d.is_base_of(d));

    assert(!d.is_derived_from(a));
    assert(!d.is_derived_from(b));
    assert(!d.is_derived_from(c));
    assert( d.is_derived_from(d));
}
```

If you wish, you might add a `type_info*` member to `inheritance_checker` to get the extra functionality that `type_info` provides.

Notice the symmetry between `is_base_of` and `derives_from`. Actually, you can remove one of them.

I suggest you to read [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/twisting-the-rtti-system-for-safe-dynami/229401004) article.

Comment: This is really awesome! I did not follow this exactly but it really gave me ideas! What really is important here is the function pointers. I achieved what i needed by giving my nodes a lambda on creation (like your inheritance_checker::create<>). The lambda is created via template and calls dynamic_cast<T>. I can then call the lambda WITHOUT templates. THANK YOU. I knew it would be possible to mix static and dynamic typing!

Comment: @David Jensen: Indeed, if all your types under consideration derive from the same polymorphic base class, then it's more efficient to use `dynamic_cast` than `throw`/`catch` as I did. The advantage of the `throw`/`catch` trick is that it's more general but the price to pay is that it's slower.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there anyway i can transform the `type_info*` to a template argument?

No, there is no way. Templates are a compile-time thing, RTTI is run-time. No connection between the two.

> I guess could call `decltype(*objects.begin())`, but that would require each set in every node to never be empty.

It would not require that. `decltype` doesn't evaluate its argument - it doesn't need to. It only needs to check the types. You can happily do `decltype(*a_null_pointer)` without invoking UB, since the expression is never evaluated - this is a so-called *unevaluated context*. `sizeof` belongs in the same category.

Note that this doesn't buy you much, though - you'll just get `object*&` back. You generally can't get a type from run-time information without preparing the mapping first.

Comment: Does decltype(base*) give me the "real" derrived type? Because my sets of object* does hold more defined types than object*.

Comment: @David: Oh, no, obviously not, since it's just a compile-time thing aswell. :) You can't get a type from runtime information without preparing a mapping before-hand.

Comment: You might explicitly add to your second paragraph, that `decltype(*objects.begin())` won't buy anything at all, just returning `object*`, even if your first paragraph already states this in general.

Comment: As ecatmur said i obviously need to do the check trough dynamic_cast. But dynamic cast still takes a type and not a type_info. So i am back to square one.

Comment: @DavidJensen It doesn't just take a type, but also an actual object (or rather a pointer/reference to one). But do you say you don't even have an object, but only its `type_info`? Interresting, but you won't get around using the object the `type_info` was generated from, if you can still access it. In the end now might be a good time to explain the actual problem you're trying to solve more clearly in your question.

Comment: The type_info was generated by typeid() which, in opposite to dynamic_cast, only requires a type but not a object. I solved the problem however by giving each node a void* which points to a testtype i can do dynamic_cast on. Its quite some memory overhead but will do for now.

Comment: @DavidJensen `dynamic_cast`ing a `void*`, does that even have defined semantics? So you created the `type_info` from an actual type known at compile time (since it's a type) and don't have any object it belongs to (you know `typeid` *can* work on objects, which is its whole purpose in the end)? Then you seem to know the type at compile time anyway and there isn't a need for runtime-polymorphism. Either seem to be mixing static and dynamic typing in either an interresting or a weird way, don't which yet ;)

Answer (score 4):

`is_base_of` and `decltype` are purely compile time constructs; they won't reflect the dynamic type of your objects.

`type_info` doesn't provide facilities to check subclass relationships; the only way to perform that check at runtime is to use `dynamic_cast`.  You'd need to store a `unique_ptr<base>` and see whether it can `dynamic_cast` to the derived type.

Comment: Unfortunately i guess your right. Damn this will make my tree structure slow.

Comment: But still, dynamic_cast requires a real type and not a type_info*. I am back to square one.

Comment: @David The idea is to get rid of the `type_info` completely.